# How to get host alias name in a variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

In our ansible scripts we are having a variable

```
set_fact: Obj_prefix=smoke-{{ ansible_host }}
```

this fact obj_prefix long as our ansible host name is like machinename.labname.domainname .

In our inventory file , i have captured the host name as

```
[swarmcluster]
smaster ansible_host=swarmmaster.vlab.mycompany.com
```

Instead of ansible_host if i can take alias name ,then the obj_prefix variable would be short. how to get the alias name variable? Is there any variable like ansible_hostalias ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is `inventory_hostname_short`: see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables).

Comment: thanks . the documentation link helped me. It is inventory_hostname_short which is suitable for me. can you update the answer ? I will make it as an answer

Comment: I added the `_short`.